# Case in where condition to calculate individual totals

Tags: mysql

```
select       
Count(*)
from  gl
join TRVMAINDATA msit 
on gl.TRANSACTIONID = msit.CHARGETRANSACTIONID

where gl.CREATEDDATETIME >= DATEADD(MONTH,-2,getdate()) AND 
             datediff(DAY,gl.BUSINESSPROCESSDATE,gl.CREATEDDATETIME)>=4  AND
             gl.MARKETCODE In('535','532','056','050','039','036','034','033','030','029','027','023','022','021','018','015','012','011','010','009','007','006','005','002','001' ) and DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,gl.CREATEDDATETIME),0) = '2/1/2017  12:00:00 AM'
```

The above code gives the total for market code mentioned.
But i also want the market code for other code which doesn't belog here. for example

```
select              
Count(*)
from  gl
join TRVMAINDATA msit 
on gl.TRANSACTIONID = msit.CHARGETRANSACTIONID
where gl.CREATEDDATETIME >= DATEADD(MONTH,-6,getdate()) AND 
             datediff(DAY,gl.BUSINESSPROCESSDATE,gl.CREATEDDATETIME)>=0     
    and 
    DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,gl.CREATEDDATETIME),0) = '2/1/2017  12:00:00 AM'
    AND
   (case
     when gl.MARKETCODE In('535','532','056','050','039','036','034','033','030','029','027','023','022','021','018','015','012','011','010','009','007','006','005','002','001') then 'Proprietary'
    when gl.MARKETCODE='037' then 'US' 
   else 'partner'
   end )
```

Is it possible to calculate totals of other market codes in one sql query or do i have to calculate individually?

Comment: The second query seems to be missing a condution after the final case expression

Answer (score 0):

I think you would like to do `count` with `case when` in select statement like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE 
               WHEN gl.marketcode IN ( '535', '532', '056', '050', 
                                      '039', '036', '034', '033', 
                                      '030', '029', '027', '023', 
                                      '022', '021', '018', '015', 
                                      '012', '011', '010', '009', 
                                      '007', '006', '005', '002', '001' ) THEN 1  
               ELSE NULL 
             END) AS `Proprietary`, 
       COUNT(CASE 
               WHEN gl.marketcode = '037' THEN 1 
               ELSE NULL 
             END) AS `US`, 
       COUNT(CASE 
               WHEN gl.marketcode NOT IN ( '535', '532', '056', '050', 
                                          '039', '036', '034', '033', 
                                          '030', '029', '027', '023', 
                                          '022', '021', '018', '015', 
                                          '012', '011', '010', '009', 
                                          '007', '006', '005', '002', 
                                          '001', '037' ) THEN 1 
               ELSE NULL 
             END) AS `partner` 
FROM gl 
JOIN trvmaindata msit 
ON gl.transactionid = msit.chargetransactionid 
WHERE gl.createddatetime >= DATEADD(month, -2, GETDATE()) 
AND DATEDIFF(day, gl.businessprocessdate, gl.createddatetime) >= 4 
AND DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, gl.createddatetime), 0) =  '2/1/2017  12:00:00 AM'
```